# Using find command in Bash script and excluding the subdirs

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, gnu-findutils

I wrote some function that should find a directory inside a parent directory, but the thing is that it's taking to long, probably it's searching in the subdirectories as well.
Here is my code:

```
function findMspDir () {
    mountedDir=/opt/SwDrop/
    dirToSearch=/opt/SwDrop/Repository/
    if [ ! -d $mountedDir ]; then 
        echo "The directory hasn't been found"
        exit 1;
    else
        echo "The directory is mounted"
        subDirToSearch="MSP-$versionNum"
    #   mspDir=`find $dirToSearch -name $subDirToSearch`
        mspDir=$(find /opt/SwDrop/Repository/ -name 'MSP-1.5.1.4')
        if [ "$mspDir" = "" ]; then 
            echo "The MSP directory hasn't been found"
            exit 1;
        fi
    fi
    echo "The found directory is: $mspDir"
}
```

I know for sure that the directory that i'm looking for is under `/opt/SwDrop/Repository/` and it can't be in the subdirectories.
Any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`find -maxdepth 1 -name "you_name" -a type d`

Comment: What does `-a` stands for?

Comment: logical "AND" is -a, logical "OR" is -o, it is a way to combine multiple conditions in one.

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to add `-maxdepth 1` to your find command (see [GNU Findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Directories)).